# Blackberry Facebook permissions acept button

Tags: facebook, blackberry

First, sorry for my bad english, I will try to be as clear as possible.
 I am developing a blackberry app that makes post to facebook, creates albums, post pictures in those albums, and posts the pictures in friends' walls... all of that works fine, but I have one huge problem:

When the user enters the app for the first time, through the phone, logs in, and then it takes him to a set permissions page, which only has my app's name, a cancel button, and an accept button. Now when you try to click them, nothing happens; at all, as if like they are not there at all.

Code

```
private final static String[] PERMISSION = Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS;

private final static String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
private final static String APPLICATION_ID = "my_id";
private final static String APPLICATION_SECRET = "my_secret";

public static ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL,
        APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSION);

public static Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
```

---

Further Investigation

---

With a program called WireShark, I catched the URL that is being requested, and the display=wap was placed, but even changing it to display=touch the problem still remains. Using display page or popup makes it too heavy for blackberry to use the website. As well, I pasted this URL on firefox and using Firebug I realized that the two buttons don't have a method in the onClick HTML field, and no javascript comes from the request. I am using the facebook sdk made by E. Baskoro on the latest version

---

facebook developers page has a bug report on this issue (not by me)

---

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320629631363983

Comment: please post the code you are using to setup your Facebook session, including the value for your `nextUrl` variable.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430718/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-for-asking-permission-in-blackberry

Comment: mmm, no, those are device permissions, my problem is with the facebook SDK, to get facebook permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in the post above, this is a facebook bug. Unless they solve it, there is no posible solution. As for me, what I ended up doing is placing an alert telling the user to give permissions to the application from their computer, and providing the option to send the facebook app URL to their email. Once the facebook bug is fixed, I shall change that behaviour.